# $window.print() executing before lines above it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My problem with the code below is that $window.print() is executing before    $scope.loading_status=false which doesn't allow me the hide certain DOM elements before printing the page out.  How can i fix this?

```
  $scope.print_error_response=function(){
     $scope.loading_status=false;
     $window.print();    
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment of `$scope.loading_status` *does* happen before the `$window.print()` call as this is the nature of Javascript. What you are probably seeing (as I can't see how you are hiding DOM elements) is the asynchronous nature of Javascript as Angular has not updated the DOM until after the "digest cycle" that evaluates all the scopes.

The reason that wrapping the `$window.print()` call in a `$timeout` is because that schedules the `print()` method invocation to happen *after* angular finishes the digest cycle and updates the DOM (thereby hiding "certain DOM elements")

here's a decent explanation of the Javascript event loop: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
 $timeout(function() {
            $window.print();
      })
```